# ASP Core Cookie Auth, Added Claim Expires Early

Tags: cookies, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm encountering this weird problem... when a user is signed in (using `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`), I then redirect them to a razor page where they choose some setting and then I add a claim to their cookie using `signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync`, but that claim appears to go become invalid or get lost before the cookie expires - the user is still logged in, but his cookie appears to no longer have the claim I added...

Is this expected behaviour, and if so, how do I make it so that the claim is valid until the entire cookie expires?  Is know you can't change a cookie after the user signs in, so is there another way I can acheive this?

This is how I add cookies in my Startup.cs:

```
  .AddIdentityCookies(c => c.ApplicationCookie.Configure(a =>
  {
    a.SlidingExpiration = true;
    a.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60 * 8);
    a.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = HandleCookieRedirect;
    a.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = HandleCookieRedirect;
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the "IsPersistent" = true for your cookie?
Also note that ExpiresUtc takes "UTC" format , so make sure you are using:
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(xxx) method or equivalent to add expiry time.

Comment: I do set IsPersistent, its based on if the user checked the 'remember me' box when I call `signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync`  This is how I add the claim await `signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, RememberMe, new[] { new Claim(WebConstants.GroupClaim, SelectedGroup.ToString()) })`  is there a way to set the expiration on just that claim?